# How do I get a Google visualization Table to sort on formatted cell values when present?

Tags: javascript, sorting, events, google-visualization

I'm using numerous Google visualization Tables to display a variety of data in a single-paged, multi-tabbed web app. Some of these tables have columns that use formatted values. When a user clicks on the column header for these columns, the data is sorted according to the sort order of the underlying values rather than the sort order of the formatted values. This results in some cases in the data not appearing to the user to be sorted.

I'm looking for a way to fix this that can be reused across all my Tables, preferably by writing one event listener that can be attached to each Table and will handle all of the specifics regardless of the data types used in the various columns of the various associated DataTables, and regardless of whether any given column uses formatted values. I do have the condition that if any cell in a column uses a formatted value, then all of the cells in that column do, but I do not have the condition that every column uses formatted values. If a column does not use formatted values, then I want the normal sort based on the type of data in the column (e.g., number, string, date, etc.).

As an example, I could have a DataTable like the following. (This data is not actual data, but mirror situations that are problematic for me.)

```
var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable({
    cols: [
        {type: 'number', label: 'ID'},
        {type: 'number', label: 'Places'},
        {type: 'string', label: 'Things'}
    ],
    rows: [
        {c:[{v:1},{v:102735,f:'Harbor Place'},{v:'pet',f:'Dalmation'}]},
        {c:[{v:2},{v:163848,f:'Alphaville'},{v:'my',f:'Top Favorites'}]},
        {c:[{v:3},{v:113787,f:'Beta City'},{v:'ten',f:'Best Things'}]}
    ]
});
```

Without my doing any special configuration, this table, if sorted ascending on the ID column, would look like this, as the user would expect:

```
ID   Places          Things
----------------------------------
1    Harbor Place    Dalmation
2    Alphaville      Top Favorites
3    Beta City       Best Things
```

If the user clicks on the header for the Places column, the table then looks like this, because the ascending sort is performed on the underlying numeric values:

```
ID   Places          Things
----------------------------------
1    Harbor Place    Dalmation
3    Beta City       Best Things
2    Alphaville      Top Favorites
```

The user, however, expects the table to look like this:

```
ID   Places          Things
----------------------------------
2    Alphaville      Top Favorites
3    Beta City       Best Things
1    Harbor Place    Dalmation
```

If the user clicks on the header for the Things column, the table would sort ascending as follows, because of the sort order of the underlying string values:

```
ID   Places          Things
----------------------------------
2    Alphaville      Top Favorites
1    Harbor Place    Dalmation
3    Beta City       Best Things
```

The user is expecting this:

```
ID   Places          Things
----------------------------------
3    Beta City       Best Things
1    Harbor Place    Dalmation
2    Alphaville      Top Favorites
```

I've searched on StackOverflow and on Google and haven't found any discussion of this particular situation. So I've been working on writing my own event listener, but it quickly became very involved when trying to write it as something that can be reused for any of my Tables. So am I missing something simple? Has anyone else had a situation like this and resolved it; if so, what did you do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the [DataView Class](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataView) to set the row order

`dataView.setRows([1, 2, 0]);`

then draw the chart with the DataView

`table.draw(dataView, options);`

getting the order of the rows during the `'sort'` event is the tricky part,
since there aren't any convenience methods for formatted values, such as `getDistinctValues`

in the following working snippet, the formatted values are extracted into an array,
sorted, then `getFilteredRows` is used to get the row index of the formatted value

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable({
      cols: [
        {type: 'number', label: 'ID'},
        {type: 'number', label: 'Places'},
        {type: 'string', label: 'Things'}
      ],
      rows: [
        {c:[{v:1},{v:102735,f:'Harbor Place'},{v:'pet',f:'Dalmation'}]},
        {c:[{v:2},{v:163848,f:'Alphaville'},{v:'my',f:'Top Favorites'}]},
        {c:[{v:3},{v:113787,f:'Beta City'},{v:'ten',f:'Best Things'}]}
      ]
    });

    // use DataView to set order of rows
    var dataView = new google.visualization.DataView(dataTable);
    dataView.setRows([1, 2, 0]);

    var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    var options = {
      // use event to set order
      sort: 'event',

      // set column arrow
      sortColumn: 1,
      sortAscending: true
    };

    google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'sort', function(props) {
      var sortValues = [];
      var sortRows = [];
      var sortDirection = (props.ascending) ? 1 : -1;

      // load values into sortable array
      for (var i = 0; i < dataTable.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
        sortValues.push({
          v: dataTable.getValue(i, props.column),
          f: dataTable.getFormattedValue(i, props.column)
        });
      }
      sortValues.sort(function (row1, row2) {
        return row1.f.localeCompare(row2.f) * sortDirection;
      });

      // set row indexes
      sortValues.forEach(function (sortValue) {
        sortRows.push(dataTable.getFilteredRows([{column: props.column, value: sortValue.v}])[0]);
      });

      // use DataView to set order of rows
      dataView.setRows(sortRows);

      // set column arrow
      options.sortColumn = props.column;
      options.sortAscending = props.ascending;

      table.draw(dataView, options);
    });

    table.draw(dataView, options);
  },
  packages: ['table']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Indeed, it does help. After looking over your solution, @WhiteHat, and given my research, I don't believe there's any more simple a solution than this. I've upvoted your answer, which will show up some day when I reach 15 rep. Thanks!

Comment: Note for those who come after: this solution as-is will not sort columns according to their natural sorting order when you haven't specified a formatted value. The call to getFormattedValue will convert the original value to string and the code then proceeds to performing a string-based sort, regardless of the original data type of the data. I still have to figure out that part, and may have to ask another question in regards to that.

Comment: you could save a reference to `rows`, prior to creating the `DataTable`, then use it in place of `sortValues` above -- the references become a little more difficult but all the info needed should be there...

Comment: In the event listener, I want to avoid referencing anything external to the DataTable in determining the type of sort to do. I might use column properties on the DataTable to handle this issue. If a column is to be sorted on the formatted values, a particular property for that column will be set to true. This way, untouched DataTables will continue to be sorted as they always have been. Only DataTables with specially marked columns will be sorted according to their formatted values. Going this route won't require much of a change to the code you supplied in your answer.

Comment: In addition to keeping track of the `v` and `f` values, I had to keep track of the `row` number in the `sortValues` objects too and use that when pushing the row number to the `sortRows` array, rather than using a return value from `getFilteredRows`. This was to distinguish between multiple rows with the same value in the sorted column.