# Google Chart: Get Column Count in Dashboard for Bar Chart

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I have a JSON data like below to build a dashboard in google chart.
I would like to draw a monthly bar chart with x-axis as scan_time (Month) and y-axis as count of tag_id's that comes into that month. The tag_ids can be duplicate.

Input data in JSON:

```
 [ 
       {  
          "tag_id":"04:0f",
          "scan_time":"2016-09-29 06:47:47",
       },
       {  
          "tag_id":"04:0f",
          "scan_time":"2016-09-29 14:48:42",
       },
       {  
          "tag_id":"99:9n",
          "scan_time":"2016-10-29 06:47:47",
       },
       {  
          "tag_id":"05:m8",
          "scan_time":"2016-11-29 06:48:42",
       }
    ]
```

something like

```
Month       Count
    Sept        2
    Oct         1
    Nov         1
```

Comment: you'll need to transform the json [into a format google will accept](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#constructor_1), are you planning to use javascript to manipulate the data?

Comment: Yes I am formatting the data into the Datatable so the Google Chart can accept it in Javascript. But cannot understand how to write a query on the prepared datatable to get count of "tag_id" to make a Bar chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

once JSON is loaded into a DataTable,

use the Data Manipulation Method --> [group()](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#google_visualization_data_group)

which returns an aggregated DataTable

see following working snippet,
the group method converts the first column to a 'month' string,
and aggregates the count of tag id's for each 'month'

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages:['table']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['date', 'tag_id'],
    [new Date('2016-09-29 06:47:47'), '04:0f'],
    [new Date('2016-09-29 14:48:42'), '04:0f'],
    [new Date('2016-10-29 06:47:47'), '99:9n'],
    [new Date('2016-11-29 06:48:42'), '05:m8'],
  ]);

  var formatDate = new google.visualization.DateFormat({pattern: 'MMMM'});

  var dataGroup = google.visualization.data.group(
    data,

    // group by column
    [{
      column: 0,
      label: 'Month',
      modifier: function (val) {
        return formatDate.formatValue(val);
      },
      type: 'string'
    }],

    // agg columns
    [{
      aggregation: google.visualization.data.count,
      column: 1,
      label: 'Tag Count',
      type: 'number'
    }]
  );

  var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  table.draw(dataGroup);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

**EDIT**

use a DataView to custom sort the rows

```
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(dataGroup);
view.setRows([2, 1, 0]);
```

use `view` to draw the Table chart, and any other charts...

the following snippet includes a ColumnChart...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages:['corechart', 'table']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['date', 'tag_id'],
    [new Date('2016-09-29 06:47:47'), '04:0f'],
    [new Date('2016-09-29 14:48:42'), '04:0f'],
    [new Date('2016-10-29 06:47:47'), '99:9n'],
    [new Date('2016-11-29 06:48:42'), '05:m8'],
  ]);

  var formatDate = new google.visualization.DateFormat({pattern: 'MMMM'});

  var dataGroup = google.visualization.data.group(
    data,

    // group by column
    [{
      column: 0,
      label: 'Month',
      modifier: function (val) {
        return formatDate.formatValue(val);
      },
      type: 'string'
    }],

    // agg columns
    [{
      aggregation: google.visualization.data.count,
      column: 1,
      label: 'Tag Count',
      type: 'number'
    }]
  );

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(dataGroup);
  view.setRows([2, 1, 0]);

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(view);

  var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
  table.draw(view);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
<div id="table_div"></div>
```

**EDIT 2**

using a ChartWrapper, set the `view` as the `dataTable` property, e.g.

```
var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
  chartType: 'Table',
  containerId: 'table_div',
  dataTable: view
});
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages:['corechart', 'table']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['date', 'tag_id'],
    [new Date('2016-09-29 06:47:47'), '04:0f'],
    [new Date('2016-09-29 14:48:42'), '04:0f'],
    [new Date('2016-10-29 06:47:47'), '99:9n'],
    [new Date('2016-11-29 06:48:42'), '05:m8'],
  ]);

  var formatDate = new google.visualization.DateFormat({pattern: 'MMMM'});

  var dataGroup = google.visualization.data.group(
    data,

    // group by column
    [{
      column: 0,
      label: 'Month',
      modifier: function (val) {
        return formatDate.formatValue(val);
      },
      type: 'string'
    }],

    // agg columns
    [{
      aggregation: google.visualization.data.count,
      column: 1,
      label: 'Tag Count',
      type: 'number'
    }]
  );

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(dataGroup);
  view.setRows([2, 1, 0]);

  var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'ColumnChart',
    containerId: 'chart_div',
    dataTable: view
  });
  chart.draw();

  var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'Table',
    containerId: 'table_div',
    dataTable: view
  });
  table.draw();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
<div id="table_div"></div>
```

Comment: fyi: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39228339/5090771) has tips for custom sorting table charts...

Comment: I do not get how to order month from Jan to Dec, kindly help!!

Comment: I am able to sort the datatable based on month but when I use those values and make a column chart I get unsorted months which does not look nice.

Comment: How can I embed Dataview in ChartWrapper? I guess there is only option for embedding Datatable but not Dataview.

Comment: Giving an error that "Cannot draw chart: no data specified" by using

Comment: new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
 'chartType': 'ColumnChart',
 'containerId': 'chart1',
 view: view});  
 columnChart1.draw();

Comment: Works fine, appreciate your efforts