# Grouping Dates in Google Graphs using google.visualization.data.group to show Week/Month etc

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, grouping, loader, googlevis

I have Google Graphs running successfully (using gstatic.com/charts/loader.js) and I am graphing with the following type of data ;

```
['Date','Sales This Year','Sales Prior Year'],
['2019-02-21',132,121],['2019-02-22',126,133],
['2019-02-23',151,129],['2019-02-24',149,137],
['2019-02-25',124,131],['2019-02-26',130,119],
['2019-02-27',130,126],['2019-02-28',131,120],
['2019-03-01',136,120],['2019-03-02',149,135],
['2019-03-03',146,138],['2019-03-04',125,128],
['2019-03-05',132,118],['2019-03-06',134,122],
['2019-03-07',131,121], ]);
```

I'm happy with the performance but I am manually saving a total in an array for Weekly Data and Monthly Data but is there a quicker way using google.visualization.data.group to compress this information into a week / month view?

I was thinking of then using new Date(year, 0, week * 7) to solve the date issue if showing by week etc.

Also, could you use google.visualization.data.group to group data into a Mon-Sun format so if you have 4 records for Mondays it would group the data into Monday, Tuesday and so on? i.e. showing sales by day of the week rather than a continuous by date view?

Many thanks in advance for any help, advice or direction on this!

Comment: try this https://jsfiddle.net/v0w5ehsc/

Comment: Thanks @abhinavxeon I'm using google.visualization.arrayToDataTable to push the data into the graph so I'm not sure if this is going to cause issues with the dates, or indeed if I should convert to the style you used in the JSFiddle.
Small bug in the JSFiddle and it didn't work online but I will keep working on this. I appreciate your help and the code you uploaded!

Comment: the `group()` method provides a [modifier function](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#creating_a_modifier_function) you can use to change the format of the date to week or month before grouping -- [here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40020571/5090771)...

Comment: Thank you once again @whitehat - I will give that a go.I'm using google.visualization.arrayToDataTable and I see in the code the date is always supplied as new Date('2016-09-29 06:47:47') - is this the best practice way to enter the date into google graphs api?

Comment: not actually, that is an old answer, I'm not one to recommend best practices, but I typically use the following constructor when possible --> `new Date(year, monthIndex [, day [, hours [, minutes [, seconds [, milliseconds]]]]]);`

Comment: I appreciate that @whitehat - I have moved to that format and I'm getting a bit more success from that. Thank you!