# Can Google Charts grouped data be ordered by chronological month name?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am using google charts to build a dashboard using a JSON result from a LINQ query. I have been successful building a table chart grouped by month, however I would like to display the months in chronological order instead of alphabetic order.

I have tried passing a date instead of the string month name, but then I am no longer able to group by month - it groups by date instead.

I have also tried passing both the month number and the month name {v: monthNum, f: monthName} but this seems to get lost somewhere once I do the aggregation.

This code is primarily based on many examples I found here on SO in answers by WhiteHat (https://stackoverflow.com/users/5090771/whitehat).

```
var heading = ["Month", "Category"];
arrOutside[0] = heading;

for (var i = 0; i < dataJson.length; i++) {
     var arr = [dataJson[i].ReportMonth, dataJson[i].Category];                        
     arrOutside[i + 1] = arr;
}

var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrOutside);

var groupData = google.visualization.data.group(
    data,
    [1, 0],
    [{
        column: 1,
        aggregation: google.visualization.data.count,
        type: 'number'
     }]
);

var view = new google.visualization.DataView(groupData);

var aggColumns = [];

var viewColumns = [0];

groupData.getDistinctValues(1).forEach(function (category, index) {
     viewColumns.push({
          calc: function (dt, row) {
              if (dt.getValue(row, 1) === category) {
                   return dt.getValue(row, 2);
              }
              return null;
          },
          label: category,
          type: 'number'
     });

     aggColumns.push({
         aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum,
         column: index + 1,
         label: category,
         type: 'number'
     });
});

view.setColumns(viewColumns);

var aggData = google.visualization.data.group(
    view,
    [0],
    aggColumns
);

var chart = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(aggData);
```

This code results in a table like so:
Category | Apr | Feb | Jan | Mar

but I would like it to show:
Category | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr

Is this possible?

**EDIT**

This code successfully creates a table with the months listed in chronological order, however it groups all the categories together as one category and gives me a total count, instead of the individual category count I had with the previous code.  I just don't know how to properly combine the two...

```
function (dataJson) {

    var arrOutside = new Array();

    var heading = ["Month", "Category"];
    arrOutside[0] = heading;

    for (var i = 0; i < dataJson.length; i++) {                        

          var arr = [new Date(dataJson[i].ReportDate), dataJson[i].Category];                        
          arrOutside[i + 1] = arr;
    }                                        

    var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrOutside);

    var formatDate = new google.visualization.DateFormat({ pattern: 'MMM' });

    var dataGroup = google.visualization.data.group(
        data,
        [{
            column: 0,
            label: 'Month',
            modifier: function (val) {
            return formatDate.formatValue(val);
            },
            type: 'string'
        }],

        [{
            aggregation: google.visualization.data.count,
            column: 1,
            label: "Category Count",
            type: 'number'
        }]
    );

    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(dataGroup);
    view.setRows([2, 1, 3, 0]);

    var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
         chartType: 'ColumnChart',
         containerId: 'chart_div',
         dataTable: view
    });
    chart.draw();

    var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
         chartType: 'Table',
         containerId: 'table_div',
         dataTable: view
    });
    table.draw()

}
```

Comment: did you see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40020571/5090771)?

Comment: Thank you. No, I hadn't seen that but I just gave it a try and got this error: c.getTimezoneOffset is not a function.

Comment: @WhiteHat okay I successfully got it to sort in chronological order with the answer you referenced, however it only calculates the total of all categories per month. My original code was grouping by category then by month.  Whenever I try to do this now, it says "All series on a given axis must be of the same data type" ...any ideas?

Comment: @WhiteHat added the latest code...thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, need to group by both month and category in the first group method.

```
var dataGroup = google.visualization.data.group(
  data,
  [1, {  // <-- add index for category
    column: 0,
    label: 'Month',
    modifier: function (val) {
      return formatDate.formatValue(val);
    },
    type: 'string'
  }],
  [{
    aggregation: google.visualization.data.count,
    column: 1,
    label: "Category Count",
    type: 'number'
  }]
);
```

next, still need to aggregate by column as in your first snippet above.

```
// create columns for each month
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(dataGroup);
var aggColumns = [];
var viewColumns = [0];
dataGroup.getDistinctValues(1).forEach(function (category, index) {
  viewColumns.push({
    calc: function (dt, row) {
      if (dt.getValue(row, 1) === category) {
        return dt.getValue(row, 2);
      }
      return null;
    },
    label: category,
    type: 'number'
  });

  aggColumns.push({
    aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum,
    column: index + 1,
    label: category,
    type: 'number'
  });
});
view.setColumns(viewColumns);
var aggData = google.visualization.data.group(
  view,
  [0],
  aggColumns
);
```

then we can set the chronological order.

```
// set columns in chron order
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(aggData);
var viewColumns = [0];
var monthOrder = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
monthOrder.forEach(function (month, index) {
  for (var i = 1; i < aggData.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
    if (aggData.getColumnLabel(i) === month) {
      viewColumns.push(i);
    }
  }
});
view.setColumns(viewColumns);
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['controls']
}).then(function () {
  // process json data
  var dataJson = [
    {ReportDate: '04/01/2019', Category: 'A'},
    {ReportDate: '04/02/2019', Category: 'A'},
    {ReportDate: '04/03/2019', Category: 'A'},
    {ReportDate: '05/04/2019', Category: 'A'},
    {ReportDate: '05/05/2019', Category: 'A'},
    {ReportDate: '05/06/2019', Category: 'A'},
    {ReportDate: '06/07/2019', Category: 'A'},
    {ReportDate: '06/08/2019', Category: 'A'},
    {ReportDate: '06/09/2019', Category: 'A'},
    {ReportDate: '07/10/2019', Category: 'A'},
    {ReportDate: '04/01/2019', Category: 'B'},
    {ReportDate: '04/02/2019', Category: 'B'},
    {ReportDate: '04/03/2019', Category: 'B'},
    {ReportDate: '05/04/2019', Category: 'B'},
    {ReportDate: '05/05/2019', Category: 'B'},
    {ReportDate: '05/06/2019', Category: 'B'},
    {ReportDate: '06/07/2019', Category: 'B'},
    {ReportDate: '06/08/2019', Category: 'B'},
    {ReportDate: '06/09/2019', Category: 'B'},
    {ReportDate: '07/10/2019', Category: 'B'}
  ];
  var arrOutside = new Array();
  var heading = ['Month', 'Category'];
  arrOutside[0] = heading;
  for (var i = 0; i < dataJson.length; i++) {
    var arr = [new Date(dataJson[i].ReportDate), dataJson[i].Category];
    arrOutside[i + 1] = arr;
  }
  var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrOutside);
  var formatDate = new google.visualization.DateFormat({pattern: 'MMM'});
  var dataGroup = google.visualization.data.group(
    data,
    [1, {
      column: 0,
      label: 'Month',
      modifier: function (val) {
        return formatDate.formatValue(val);
      },
      type: 'string'
    }],
    [{
      aggregation: google.visualization.data.count,
      column: 1,
      label: "Category Count",
      type: 'number'
    }]
  );

  // create columns for each month
  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(dataGroup);
  var aggColumns = [];
  var viewColumns = [0];
  dataGroup.getDistinctValues(1).forEach(function (category, index) {
    viewColumns.push({
      calc: function (dt, row) {
        if (dt.getValue(row, 1) === category) {
          return dt.getValue(row, 2);
        }
        return null;
      },
      label: category,
      type: 'number'
    });

    aggColumns.push({
      aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum,
      column: index + 1,
      label: category,
      type: 'number'
    });
  });
  view.setColumns(viewColumns);
  var aggData = google.visualization.data.group(
    view,
    [0],
    aggColumns
  );

  // set columns in chron order
  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(aggData);
  var viewColumns = [0];
  var monthOrder = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
  monthOrder.forEach(function (month, index) {
    for (var i = 1; i < aggData.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
      if (aggData.getColumnLabel(i) === month) {
        viewColumns.push(i);
      }
    }
  });
  view.setColumns(viewColumns);

  var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'ColumnChart',
    containerId: 'chart_div',
    dataTable: view
  });
  chart.draw();

  var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'Table',
    containerId: 'table_div',
    dataTable: view
  });
  table.draw()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
<div id="table_div"></div>
```